# Symfony2 ContainerAware fails to get elements

Tags: php, class, symfony, service

I'm trying to use EntityManager to get data from an entity inside my custom class, but I'm getting this error

> Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object on line 28

I don't know why `$this->container` has no child elements, I'm extending `ContainerAware`...

this is my code

```
<?php
namespace WhiteBear\UsersBundle\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;
use WhiteBear\CustomerPortalBundle\Entity\VtigerContactdetails;
use WhiteBear\CustomerPortalBundle\Entity\VtigerContactscf;
class UserDependentRole extends ContainerAware implements RoleInterface
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getRole()
    {
        $rol = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('WhiteBearCustomerPortalBundle:VtigerContactscf')
        ->findBy(array(
                'contactid' => $this->user->getId()
        ));
        $role = $rol['groups'] == '1' ? "AGENT" : "USER";
        return 'ROLE_' . strtoupper($role);
    }

    public function getEntityManager() {
        return $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Also tried with only injecting doctrine2 via services.yml

```
<?php
namespace WhiteBear\UsersBundle\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

use WhiteBear\CustomerPortalBundle\Entity\VtigerContactdetails;
use WhiteBear\CustomerPortalBundle\Entity\VtigerContactscf;
class UserDependentRole implements RoleInterface
{
    private $user;
    private $em;

    public function __construct(UserInterface $user, EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getRole()
    {
        $rol = $this->em->getRepository('WhiteBearCustomerPortalBundle:VtigerContactscf')
        ->findBy(array(
                'contactid' => $this->user->getId()
        ));
        $role = $rol['groups'] == '1' ? "AGENT" : "USER";
        return 'ROLE_' . strtoupper($role);
    }
}
```

services.yml

```
services:
    white_bear.userdepend:
        class: WhiteBear\CustomerPortal\Security\UserDependentRole
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

But as I'm calling this class from an Entity, I'm getting this error

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to
>   WhiteBear\UsersBundle\Security\UserDependentRole::__construct() must
>   be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given

That's because from my Entity I'm doing this, because I don't know how to get EntityManager to parse into constructor...

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function getRoles() {
    return array(new UserDependentRole($this));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You've to inject the container via the [setter provided by the ContainerAware class](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerAware.html).

Here's the way you can manage this kind of injection via the DIC,

```
your_service_id:
    class:  Path_to_your_service_class
    calls:
        - [setContainer, ['@service_container']]
```

**BUT,**

As you're just targeting the Entity Manager, **you don't need** to make your class Container Aware. Injecting the container should be done only when your service rely on a set of other services (which is not the case here)

So then, please consider injecting only the `doctrine.orm.entity_manager` service. [Check this relevant Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832385/how-can-i-use-the-getcontainer-in-my-self-made-service/21832841#21832841)

Comment: Doing that on my services.yml does nothing, got the same error :(

Comment: Ok, Check the update and please consider the "BUT" section of my response.

Comment: Yeah that was my first attempt but I failed, see my update about what went wrong, is just a stupid thing but I don't know how to set the EntityManager to constructor from the class caller (in this case, an Entity)

Comment: You should rethink your implementation because your entity should not know (or rely) on any Entity Manager in order to keep a clean separation of concerns.

Comment: The point is that I'm trying to get this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836340/change-role-on-login-symfony2-fosuserbundle and that's the only way I think I can get what I need...